# Instantiate my Xib file failed (Swift 4) > crash

Tags: swift, storyboard, xib

Folders info:

[image]

This my .XIB:

[image]

The UIView associated is:

```
@IBDesignable
class RankingUserCell: UIView {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        self.addSubview(view)
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "RankingUserCell", bundle: nil)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView <<< CRASH
    }
```

This reusable view is used directly into my storyboard (standard using).

When my app starts, a crash occurs, and it's on this line:

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "RankingUserCell", bundle: nil)
            return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView <<< CRASH
        }
```

Stack trace:

[image]

From output debug trace:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Thank you very much guys for your help!

Comment: please share error message for better understanding

Comment: That's because that's not how to load a xib file.

Comment: Can you post the backtrace of the crush ?

Comment: @byaruhaf : I've updated my post

Comment: @emrcftci : I've updated my post

Comment: You have put Bundle as nil, won't it be Bundle.main (Main bundle)?